Run a CGI application on windows server 2022 via POST request - how?
I'm not a windows server pro but searching the net did not give recent answers.
Here is the setup: I have a Windows server 2022 machine. I'd like to trigger a program there by a web post request. The user sends form data f=foo and b=bar and the server should run a program with myprogram.exe -f foo -b bar.
How can I accomplish this? Security is no concern since this is a vitual server without public access with known users.

(1) browser (html form) --> POST f=foo&b=bar --> IIS(asp.net) (2) asp.net call shell  pass parameter -f foo -b bar to exe myprogram.exe

@life888888 Could you elaborate a bit on this? The frontend part (1) is clear to me. The backend part on WS2022 is not clear at all.

I have given a simple but complete implementation example in the answer area, including complete steps and program code. If you follow the steps, you should be able to complete a simple test

Delete the answer and remove the content. Because the answer was not approved and no one voted for it.

@life888888 sorry for the late answer, I was occupied by other stuff and was on vacation. I'd like to try the answer you posted and put a lot of effort in. Can it be recovered?

This is just a little personal habit of mine: I will clean up some of my answers. When they are not accepted or voted up, I will clean up these answers regularly.

Warning, the following content is for proof of concept only. For actual use, it should be adjusted according to actual needs.
Development PC

OS: Windows 10

Install and configure development software
Download DotNet SDK 7 And Install

Browser Open https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.410-windows-x64-installer

File browser open directory : Downloads

Click dotnet-sdk-7.0.410-win-x64.exe


Config NuGet

Open CMD.exe

Run Command : Add NuGet Source


dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org



Run Command : Check NuGet Source

dotnet nuget list source

Prepare project directory
Next we will create a project directory: ST_NET7_EXAMPLES
mkdir  %USERPROFILE%\Documents\ST_NET7_EXAMPLES

Project 1: MyProgram (For Test)
Create Project
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents\ST_NET7_EXAMPLES
dotnet new console -n MyProgram

Edit MyProgram\Program.cs
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    
        string fooValue = null;
        string barValue = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (args[i] == "-f" && i + 1 < args.Length)
            {
                fooValue = args[i + 1];  // Get the value after `-f`
            }
            else if (args[i] == "-b" && i + 1 < args.Length)
            {
                barValue = args[i + 1];  // Get the value after `-b`
            }
        }

        // Print results
        Console.WriteLine($"-f: {fooValue}");
        Console.WriteLine($"-b: {barValue}");
        
        // Get the user's home directory
        string userHomeDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

        // Set the path of the log file
        string logFilePath = Path.Combine(userHomeDirectory, "app.log");

        // Write to log file
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, append: true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine($"-f: {fooValue}");
            writer.WriteLine($"-b: {barValue}");
            writer.WriteLine($"Logged at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Log written to {logFilePath}");
        
    }
}

Build
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents\ST_NET7_EXAMPLES\MyProgram

dotnet build

Run
dotnet run -- -f foo -b bar

Create Publish
dotnet publish -c Release -o ..\MyProgramApp

The output of Project 1: MyProgram has been completed here.
Project 2: DemoApp (Features you want installed on Windows Server.)
Create Project
cd %USERPROFILE%\Documents\ST_NET7_EXAMPLES

dotnet new webapi -n DemoApp

We Need Add Some File
DemoApp
├── DemoApp.csproj
├── appsettings.Development.json
├── appsettings.json
├── Controllers
│   ├── DemoController.cs <Add File>
│   └── WeatherForecastController.cs
├── Models <Create Directory>
│   └── Parameters.cs <Add File>
...

Models\Parameters.cs
namespace DemoApp.Models
{
    public class Parameters
    {
        public string F { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }
}

Controllers\DemoController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

using DemoApp.Models;

namespace DemoApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DemoController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST api/demo
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Parameters parameters)
        {
            if (parameters == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid input");
            }

            // Access the parameters f and b
            var f = parameters.F;
            var b = parameters.B;

            // Print Parameters
            Console.WriteLine($"-f: {f}");
            Console.WriteLine($"-b: {b}");

            // Define the external program path
           
            string programPath = "C:\\TOOLS\\MyProgramApp\\MyProgram.exe";

            // Create the process start info
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = programPath,
                Arguments = $"-f {f} -b {b}", // Pass parameters as command line arguments
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,  // Capture standard output if needed
                RedirectStandardError = true,   // Capture standard error if needed
                UseShellExecute = false,        // Required to redirect output
                CreateNoWindow = true           // Do not create a console window
            };
            
            try
            {
                // Start the process
                using (var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
                {
                    if (process == null)
                    {
                        return StatusCode(500, "Failed to start the process");
                    }

                    // Optionally capture output (if the program writes output)
                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                    // Wait for the process to exit
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    // Check if there was any error
                    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                    {
                        return StatusCode(500, $"Process failed with exit code {process.ExitCode}: {error}");
                    }

                    // Return the output or a success message
                    return Ok(new { message = "Process completed successfully", output });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"Error running process: {ex.Message}");
            }
        
            return Ok(new { message = $"Received: f = {f}, b = {b}" });
        }
    }
}

Build Publish
dotnet publish -c Release -o ../publish

Final Result
ST_NET7_EXAMPLES
├── DemoApp
├── MyProgram
├── MyProgramApp (1)
└── publish      (2)

Please copy Directory (1) MyProgramApp (2) publish to your Windows Server.
Your Windows Server
Download And Install

Browser Open https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-7.0.20-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

In Downloads Directory , Click and run dotnet-hosting-7.0.20-win.exe


MyProgramApp Directory
COPY MyProgramApp TO C:\TOOLS
FULL PATH IS C:\TOOLS\MyProgramApp
publish Directory
COPY publish TO C:\
FULL PATH IS C:\publish
Config IIS Site
Add Web Site
Site -> Add Website...

Enter Site Data

Site name: DemoApp
Physical path: C:\publish
Click Button: OK
Ignore Warning
Because our setting *:80 is the same as the default IIS Site, there will be a warning.
Click Button Yes

Stop Default Web Site
Select Default Web Site
Click Button Stop

Start DemoApp Web Site
Select DemoApp
Click Button Start

Test
Open CMD.exe
Run Command: (In Server)
curl -X POST ^
  "http://localhost/api/demo" ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  -d "{\"f\":\"IISDemoAppHello\", \"b\":\"IISDemoAppWorld\"}"

Return:
{"message":"Process completed successfully","output":"Hello, World!\r\n-f: IISDemoAppHello\r\n-b: IISDemoAppWorld\r\nLog
 written to C:\\Users\\TEMP\\app.log\r\n"}

You Can open  C:\Users\TEMP\app.log
-f: IISDemoAppHello
-b: IISDemoAppWorld
Logged at: 9/19/2024 11:44:58 PM

Access Windows Server from other machines:
change localhost to your-Server-HostName or your-Server-IP-Address
curl -X POST ^
  "http://your-Server-HostName/api/demo" ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  -d "{\"f\":\"IISDemoAppHello\", \"b\":\"IISDemoAppWorld\"}"

curl -X POST ^
  "http://your-Server-Ip/api/demo" ^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  -d "{\"f\":\"IISDemoAppHello\", \"b\":\"IISDemoAppWorld\"}"

I don't have a corresponding Windows Server. The above steps were developed and tested on Windows 10.
Therefore, there may be differences in the settings screen of IIS deployment.
This is not a CGI program. This is a DotNet program deployed on IIS.
When you are on another machine, use your-server-name or your-Server-Ip instead of localhost used in the curl string. your-Server-Ip may be 192.168.12.112 .
